# Is Process Table the same thing as the Job Queue in UNIX?

Tags: process, operating-system

As a student that is learning Operating System, I learned that there is a data structure in the kernel space called "Process Table", which maintains all information about processes.

Later on, when I got to the topics of scheduling, I was told that all processes that got into the system would first be put into a data structure called "Job Queue", which seemed to also maintain general information about processes.

This got me thinking, is the "Process Table" here the same as the "Job Queue"? Maybe this is a trivial question, just want to make sure I understand things right. I knew that I might need to look into the Linux kernel source code to figure this out, but could anyone give me any quick insight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is Process Table the same thing as the Job Queue in UNIX?

No, they are not the same.

Read [this textbook](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/) about operating systems; and the wikipage on [processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)).

The Linux OS is mostly open source. You can download ([here](https://kernel.org/)) and study its source code, and look inside the source code of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) to understand better how [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) are used. You could also play with [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html).

See also the [kernelnewbies](https://kernelnewbies.org/) and [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/) websites.

Of course, the kernel has *a lot of data structures* (and millions lines of source code). Read more about the [kernel scheduler](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/scheduler/index.html).